# Given $\varphi:A\to B$, how do I describe the following six maps in terms of elements?

Tags: functions, morphism

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

In the context of the topic of exact sequences, I often see the following:

suppose I have a homomorphic map between groups, rings, modules, etc or a linear transformations between vector spaces:  $\varphi:A\to B,$ and let $\text{ker }\varphi,$ denote the kernel of $\varphi,$ $\text{coim }\varphi=A/
\text{ker }\varphi,$ $\text{Im }\varphi,$ to denote the image of $\varphi,$ $\text{coker }\varphi=B/\text{Im }\varphi.$ In terms of elements, we have if $a\in A,$ then $\varphi(a)=b$ for some $b\in B.$ (Depending on context in which $\varphi$ is defined, it might not make sense to discuss $B\to \text{coker }\varphi,$ etc.) Also, from the map $\varphi,$ I can create the following list of different maps:

$f_1:\text{ker }\varphi\to A,\quad (1)$

$f_2:A\to A/\text{ker }\varphi,\quad (2)$

$f_3:\text{Im }\varphi\to B,\quad (3)$

$f_4:B\to B/\text{Im }\varphi,\quad (4)$

$f_5:A/\text{ker }\varphi\to \text{Im }\varphi,\quad (5)$

$f_6:\text{ker }\varphi\to A/\text{Im }\varphi\quad (6).$

Equivalently, $(4)$ can be written as $f_4:B\to \text{coker }\varphi,$ $(5)$ can be written as $f_5:\text{coim }\varphi\to \text{Im }\varphi,$ and $(6)$ can be written as $f_6:\text{ker }\varphi\to \text{coker }\varphi.$

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

For describing the above five maps in terms of elements for the above six maps, are the following correct?

for $(1)$, if $a\in \text{ker }\varphi\subset A,$ then is $f_1$ can be described as $f_1(a)=a,$  and $(f_1\circ \varphi)(a)=f_1(\varphi(a))=f(0)=0.$

for $(2)$ if $a\in A,$ then $f_2$ can be defined as $f_2(a)=a+\text{ker }\varphi.$

for $(3)$ if $b\in \text{Im }\varphi \subset B,\exists a\in A,$ so that $\varphi(a)=b.$ But $\text{Im }\varphi\subset B,$ so $f_5(\varphi(a))=f_5(b)=b$.

for $(4)$ if $a\in A, \exists b\in B, \varphi(a)=b,$ then we have $A\xrightarrow{\varphi}B\xrightarrow{f_4}B/\text{Im }\varphi,$ defined as $f_4(\varphi(a))=f_4(b)=b+\text{Im }\varphi.$

for $(5)$ if $a\in A,$ then $f_5$ can be described as $f_5(a+\text{ker }\varphi)=\varphi(a).$

for $(6)$ if $a\in \text{ker }\varphi\subset A,$ then is $f_6$ can be described in terms of $f_6(a)=a+\text{Im }\varphi,$ and $f_6$ is surjective since it sends elements to the equivalence class of $A/\text{Im }\varphi.$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does "$f_1(\varphi(x))=f_1(0)=a$" mean? Similarly, what does "$f_6(\varphi(a))=f_6(a)+\text{Im }\varphi$" mean? Neither of these seem to make sense. Also your definitions like "$f_2(a)=f_2(a)+\text{ker }\varphi$" are along the right lines, but you can't have $f_2(a)$ on both sides of the definition.. Also in "$f_6:\text{ker }\varphi\to A/\text{Im }\varphi$", the codomain $A/\text{Im }\varphi$ doesn't make sense, since the image is not contained in $A$. For general groups or rings, $B/\text{Im }\varphi$ doesn't make sense either, since the image is not a normal subgroup/ideal.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen the reason I made my post is that for the topic of exact sequences, I often see those six maps for different purposes.  But everytime they appear, say in the case of $(1)$ $f_1:\text{ker }\varphi\to A,$ it will just say that map is an inclusion map.  But in terms of elements, it never stated how is expressed. Since $\varphi:A\to B$ and $\text{Ker }\varphi\subset A$, then if $a\in \text{ker }\varphi,$ is $f_1(a)=a$ or f_1(\varphi(a))=f_1(0)=a?.$  Another thing is,...

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen ... the six maps' domain and codomain are only defined in the context where they are allowed to be defined mathematically speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about notation, definitions and keeping your wits about you (good practice for diagram chases).

For example:

(1) $ker\space\varphi$ is a subgroup of $A$ so $f_1$ is the inclusion: $f_1(a)=a$.
For the second statement here, draw a diagram

$$ker\space\varphi\xrightarrow{f_1}A\xrightarrow{\varphi} B$$

So $\varphi(f_1(b))=0$ where $b\in ker\space\varphi$ [order matters; noted in comments]

(2) $f_2(a)= a + ker\space\varphi$; you are just sending $a$ to its equivalence class under $\varphi$. Note that if $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)$ then $f_2(a)=f_2(b)$.

The others are SIMILAR; try to work it out slowly and carefully just pay attention to where elements live and what the terms mean.

Added to finish (6):

The map must land in $coker\space\varphi=B/Im\space\varphi$

$f_6:ker\space\varphi\rightarrow B/Im\space\varphi$

note that it is the composition

$ker\space\varphi\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow B/Im\space\varphi$

where the first map is the inclusion $f_1$, the second is $\varphi$ and the third is $f_4$.  So to describe it, starting with some $a\in ker\space\varphi$, $\varphi(a)=0$ ultimately this composite is $0$. You may have intended just

$A\rightarrow coker\space\varphi$ which takes $a$ to the equivalence class of $\varphi(a)$.

Comment: I will try out the rest.  If I run into any difficulties, I will leave a question here to ask you for further clarifications, if that is okay.

Comment: I am not sure if the best approach but you could update your notes above for (3) to (6) and make clear it was revised based on feedback.

Comment: I revised it.  Can you see if it is okay?  I leave $(2), (5)$ as they are, since they are well known in terms how they can be defined in terms of elements.  Thank you.

Comment: (3) is fine, all you need say to describe it is $f_5(b)=b$ since again it is an inclusion.  In (4) it is enough to just say $f_4(b)=b+ Im\space\varphi$. Here you have assumed $\varphi$ is a surjection which is not a stated assumption, so this part about $b$ being some $\varphi(a)$ is only true in that case.  (6) is not quite there, take a look again it should be simpler.

Comment: I fixed $(6).$  Does it look correct?  I remember to mention that why the map is surjective.

Comment: The problem with $f_6$ is how it is set up before trying to say what $f_6(a)$ is; you are considering $A/Im\space\varphi$ but $Im\space\varphi\subset B$, not a subgroup of $A$ so this quotient does not make sense.- that was noted in the original comments.  Did you mean something else with (6)? Something to do with $coker$?

Comment: yeah, $(6)$ is suppose to be $f_6:\text{ker }\varphi\to \text{coker }\varphi.$   I am learning exact sequences in the context of modules and abelian groups.  I am not advanced enough to know in what context when cokernel doesn't exists.  But in the cases of modules and abelian group, how should I write $(6)$ in terms of elements?

Comment: Extended discussions in comments at this point are discouraged so I've amended my answer to include (6). Again, this is all just definitions and paying attention to which module you are in at any given step. Hope this helps.

Comment: oh i did not know i can extended it likek that.  Thank you so very much for showing me this.